# Nginx PHP MySQL ROR setup on Ubuntu Server

Tags: mysql, php, nginx, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-10.04

How would I go about installing and setting up nginx, PHP, MySQL and RoR on a Ubuntu Server 10.04.2 machine?

I have been through a few tutorials but have never found one which integrates ruby on rails. Is this not possible?

Cheers, Dean

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/ruby_with_nginx_on_ubuntu_lucid/) is a short Tutorial. But nginx is used to proxy and balance the connections to the Mongrel cluster. A real integration of rails in nginx is not possible.

But you can look into the tutorial there is a cool way to set up a Mongrel cluster and proxy the connections with nginx this is the common way i know and what i use.